# Can't access Gaming, even though I committed

Tags: support, area-51, private-beta

If I visit Area 51 it shows that I committed to the Gaming site. However now that it's in beta if I try to log in I just get the "This site is currently in private beta" page.

One thing that might be throwing this off is (as I found) my OpenID wasn't associated with my Area 51 account at the time that I committed to Gaming. But now that I've associated it, I should get access to Gaming, right?

(This also makes me think that the process of starting an Area 51 account isn't as smooth as starting accounts on other Stack sites, which seem to get associated with my OpenID without much effort.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you validate your email address on Area 51?

Are you using the same OpenID that you used to log in to Area 51? If you aren't, then you may not be able to get in.

(despite what squillman said, this is 100% tied to your OpenID)

Comment: I am having the same issue as above. My account page shows that I am committed to Area 51, but when I click "go to site" it states that the area is in private beta and not open to the public. I have the email invite, but am not able to access the site. I also did not previously have an openID associated-not any at all. I have added one now, but it still will not allow access.

Comment: Email verified. Same OpenID, but I acknowledge I didn't have my OpenID associated to Area 51 when I did the act of committing. I'm not sure if that's the cause of the problem, but it's one thing that I see different between my case and some of my friends who do have access to the site.

Comment: @JavadocMD we're fixing this so if you add your OpenID after the beta starts you can still get in

Comment: Awesome! You guys rock.